# Normalizing a geometric flow liking mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I try to normalize a flow, which is slight modification of mean curvature flow,
$$
\partial_t F = -(H-1)\nu
$$
where $F$ is position vector, $H$ is mean curvature, $\nu$ is normal vector. According to the Huisken's way, let $\tilde F = \psi F$ such that 
$$
\int d\tilde\mu_t  = \int d\mu_0
$$
i.e. keep  the area constant. So, we have 
$$
\tilde g_{ij} = \psi^2 g_{ij} ~~~~\sqrt {\tilde g} = \psi ^n \sqrt g
$$
and since 
$$
\partial \sqrt g =(H-H^2)\sqrt g 
$$
we have 
$$
0=\partial_t \int \psi^n \sqrt g   \\
=\int \psi^{n-1}\psi' \sqrt g +\int \psi^n(H-H^2)\sqrt g 
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{\psi'}{\psi} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{\int (H^2 -H)\sqrt g}{\int \sqrt g}
$$
let 
$$
h_1= \frac{\int H \sqrt g}{\int \sqrt g}  ~~~~~~~~ h_2 = \frac{\int H^2 \sqrt g}{\int \sqrt g}
$$
so
$$
\tilde h_2 = \psi^{-2} h_2 ~~~~~~~~ \tilde h_1 = \psi^{-1}h_1
$$
Generally, for offset $\psi$ we must let $\tilde t =\tilde t(t)$, the way of Huisken is 
$$
\tilde t(t) = \int_0^t  \psi^2(\tau) d\tau    ~~~~~
\frac{dt}{d\tilde t}=\psi^{-2}
$$
Then, we have 
$$
\partial _t \tilde F 
=\frac{dt}{d\tilde t}[\psi' F  + \psi \partial_t F]
=\frac{dt}{d\tilde t}
[
\frac{\psi}{n} h_2 F   
-\frac{\psi}{n} h_1 F
-\psi H \nu 
+\psi \nu
]
$$
But the $\psi$ can't be completely offset. How to do the normalize of this flow ?